# XML to Linq C# retrieve entries from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to to the following task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Eintrag>
<Kunde>
    <Email> example@test.de  </Email>
    <Kundennummer>1234567 </Kundennummer>
</Kunde>
<Kunde>
    <Email> example1@test.de  </Email>
    <Kundennummer>1234569 </Kundennummer>
</Kunde>
</Eintrag>
```

I need to save `Email` and `Kundennummer` of each `Kunde` in a String.

Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the Linq to XML documentation? There's examples of that exact scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-descendants-with-a-specific-element-name

Comment: This question is lacking most of the information we need to really help you.  Please read **[ask]** and then come back and improve the question :)

Comment: How do you want them saved in a string? What's your required outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("Kunde").Select(x => new
            {
                email = (string)x.Element("Email"),
                num = (string)x.Element("Kundennummer")
            }).ToList();


        }
    }

}
```